# Pycharm snap folder empty, how to create desktop file

Tags: snap, desktop-file

I installed Pycharm community edition by:

```
sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic
```

The IDE has been installed and it's working fine, but now I wanted to create a desktop file in order to add it to the launchbar. The problem is, the snap folder appears to be empty:

[image]

So I don't know which path I should set when creating the desktop file.